# How to store multiple <image> tags click into an array using Javascript?

Tags: javascript, jquery, arrays, image

There are multiple images in my HTML file. When a users click them, their IDs should be populated.
There is no problem in getting those IDs.

How can we do the following stuff

1) Storing all these IDs in an array when user clicks on multiple images.

- Ex :

  ```
  array = img01 ; array = img02 ; 
  final array = img01|img02|img03|....... based on the number of clicks made by the user
  ```

2) Passing this array to an another function
This array should be passed to a OnClick() function

3) The function to which the array was passed is a button click function which should not take any parameters.

Can anyone help me on how to accomplish this task using JQuery or JavaScript ?

Thanks
Sandy.

Comment: Why you need to store the ID's  .... It's unclear but for me seems like you try to get all selected imgs by click and then do something with that collection, if that is the case you can simply add a classname and then call the entire collection https://jsfiddle.net/aeLuon35/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Initialize an array:

```
var ids = [];
```

When you want to add an ID, utilize Array's push method:

```
ids.push(id);
```

Access it from a function:

```
function theOnClickFunction(){
    console.log(ids);
}
```

Comment: Yeah.. I have used the push method to push all the IDs into an array.However, <img onClick="function(this.id)"  id="XYZ" style='position: absolute; left: 113px; top: 149px;' src="sample.gif"  width="20'" height="20"/>.... Here, I just want to separate two functionalities.... Extraction of ids from the images ( collects IDs and displays them using alert) and  Updating the images ( Drawing the images based on the pop-up confirmation) .. These are two different methods.. calling anyone in other would misleads the application or user

Comment: What about removals? It's much easier to just generate the array when the form is submit.

Comment: @RoryMcCrossan Undoubtedly, if that's what OP intended to do. I was just answering the question as asked.